# Spark .stdev() Python Issues

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark

So I am trying to do some statistical analysis I've been doing sum a bit differently than stdev.

Sum works fine like this:

```
stats[0] = myData2.map(lambda (Column, values): (sum(values))).collect()
```

Stdev is formatted differently and does not work correctly:

```
stats[4] = myData2.map(lambda (Column, values): (values)).stdev()
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'ResultIterable' and 'float'
```

Answer (score 1):

First solution use [NumPy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.std.html#numpy.std)

```
data=[(1,[1,2,3,4,5]),(2,[6,7,8,9]),(3,[1,3,5,7])]
dataRdd = sc.parallelize(data)
import numpy
dataRdd.mapValues(lambda values: numpy.std(values)).collect()
# Result
# [(1, 1.4142135623730951), (2, 1.1180339887498949), (3, 2.2360679774997898)]
```

Second solution DIY and do it more distributed

```
data = [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 6), (2, 7), (2, 8), (2, 9), (3, 1), (3, 3), (3, 5), (3, 7)]
# Generate RDD of (Key, (Sum, Sum of squares, Count))
dataSumsRdd = dataRdd.aggregateByKey((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                         lambda (sum, sum2, count), value: (sum + float(value), sum2 + float(value**2), count+1.0),
                         lambda (suma, sum2a, counta), (sumb, sum2b, countb): (suma + sumb, sum2a + sum2b, counta + countb))
# Generate RDD of (Key, (Count, Average, Std Dev))
import math
dataStatsRdd = dataSumsRdd.mapValues(lambda (sum, sum2, count) : (count, sum/count, math.sqrt(sum2/count - (sum/count)**2)))
# Result
# [(1, (5.0, 3.0, 1.4142135623730951)), (2, (4.0, 7.5, 1.118033988749895)), (3, (4.0, 4.0, 2.23606797749979))]
```

Comment: I am getting this when I try and print it later: Standard Dev: PythonRDD[166] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:43

Comment: Thanks. How would I strip out just the standard deviation out of the second solution?

Comment: Just change the final mapValues call and make it return the std dev alone instead of a tuple